# Sharing custom spellfile between multiple machines

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using vim extensively for text processing on multiple machines. It's quite straightforward to share the configuration using a plugins manager and a git repository containing all settings.

The problem that I was not able to solve yet is how I can share the [spellfile](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'spellfile') automatically.

Is there any practical solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can easily put it to your Dropbox / Google Drive. Therefore the path would be similar on different machines and syncing is going to be the problem of the tools. Additionally, you can commit it to your git and create own dotfiles repo with it.